# IF statement in Data Flow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

In OLE DB Source I use below code (SQL command from variable - I get table name from variable) to handle nonexisting tables (I have to iterate through all tables list and get data from existing tables):

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'KLIENT_PRZEKROCZENIA'))

BEGIN 
select max(REPO_DATE) REPO_DATE_SQLServer from KLIENT_PRZEKROCZENIA END 
ELSE 
select NULL  REPO_DATE_SQLServer
```

It's work in MS, but in SSIS I get:

> ### TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> Error at max(REPO_DATE) [SQL Server [122]]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL
>   Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid
>   object name 'KLIENT_PRZEKROCZENIA'.".
>
> Error at max(REPO_DATE) [SQL Server [122]]: Unable to retrieve column
>   information from the data source. Make sure your target table in the
>   database is available.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC020204A
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)

This result is merged with another OLE DB Source (this source have all tables) in the same Data Flow:

[image: Flow]

How to handle missing tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine the following should work.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
               WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'KLIENT_PRZEKROCZENIA')
   SELECT CAST(NULL AS DATE) AS REPO_DATE_SQLServer
ELSE
   EXEC ('SELECT MAX(REPO_DATE) REPO_DATE_SQLServer from KLIENT_PRZEKROCZENIA')
```

Comment: Would be interested to know if this works.  You're assuming that the query against the non-existent table is being parsed even though it's not executed?  Is that right?

Comment: @Brett yes, it is trying to get the column metadata that the result will return and that bit is failing. So hopefully providing it in the first branch and hiding the second branch in `exec` should allow that to succeed.

Comment: Nice.  One to remember when I get a head-scratching moment in the future :)

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @PNPTestovir!

Answer (score 0):

This should tell whether there is a user table existing in a SQL Server database:

```
if (exists (select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = 'KLIENT_PRZEKROCZENIA'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if exists (
select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = 'Your table name')
Begin 
    print 'its here'
end
else
Begin
    print 'its not here'
end
```

Comment: You tested it? It's looks like my example.